# how to translate or redirect a URL in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, url

I have to translate or redirect the URL request content in my web application.

i.e if the request was...

```
http://localhost/update/homepage.aspx?lang=de
```

then, i have to automatically translate it to a more specific language locale.

```
http://localhost/update/homepage.aspx?lang=de-DE
```

My question is how do i achieve the same ? Should i use any client javascripts which does the job of conversion from "**de**" to "**de-DE**" ?

Or is there any better solution

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `Page_Load` of your page you can check for this

```
if(lang == "de")
    Server.Transfer("~/update/homepage.aspx?lang=de-DE")
```

May be this could help, without implementing any Routing in your application.

Comment: How do i redirect when this web application is hosted on a webserver ? The localhost doesn't make sense at that point of time

Comment: you don't need a host name in a server.transfer, just a path as it happens within the server.

Comment: @yogi : Though this line is executed, but i still see the old url in my browser. I'm not sure whether this worked or not :(

Comment: If you want the URL changed use Response.Redirect instead of Server.Transfer

Comment: Yes @Blachshma is right,
I wrote `Server.Transfer` for performance point of view

Answer (score 1):

How about using [URL Rewriting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx#urlrewriting_topic6)?